# Print (to printer!) Python source code with syntax highlighting via command line (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, printing

Sometimes I'd like to just print out the source code, but I'd also like syntax highlighting.  What is a good way to do this from the command line?

The solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43523) doesn't work for me -- the text just runs off the bottom of the page, in addition, I would prefer to not have to deal with temporary files.  And I'm having a hard time find solutions that aren't geared towards just providing an output *file*, which I don't need or want.

I'm imaging a solution like

```
>> newcmd module.py | lpr
```

where `newcmd` is whatever it is that takes the source, prettifies it into pdf, and then dumps to stdout.

I'm not looking to beautify the code in terms of it's formatting, just getting syntax highlighting in the printout.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913324/python-source-formatter-pretty-printer and https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=pretty+print+python+code